# Matplotlib: combination of inverted plots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to achieve the following effect using matplotlib:

[image]

As you can see it's a combination of plots in different quadrants.

I do know how to generate each quadrant individually. For example, for the 'x invert' quadrant's plot I would simply use:

```
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.show()
```

to draw the plot. It properly inverts the `x` axis. However, it would only generate top-left quadrant's plot for me.

How can I generate a combination of plots described in the above picture? Each quadrant has its own plot with different inverted axises.

My best idea was to merge it in some tool like Paint.

Comment: You need 4 subplots on a 2x2 grid. For the first invert the x axis, for the fourth invert the y axis and for the third invert both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to add a comment to add on to ImportanceOfBeingErnest's comment, but when you create the 4 subplots you'll want to remove the space between the plots as well as have shared axes (and clean up overlapping ticks).

There are various ways to do subplots, but I prefer gridspec. You can create a 2x2 grid with gridspec and do all of this, here's an example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

fig = plt.figure()

# lines to plot
x = np.arange(0, 10)
y = np.arange(0, 10)

# gridspec for 2 rows, 2 cols with no space between
grid = gridspec.GridSpec(nrows=2, ncols=2, hspace=0, wspace=0, figure=fig)

x_y = fig.add_subplot(grid[0, 1], zorder=3)
x_y.plot(x, y)
x_y.margins(0)

invx_y = fig.add_subplot(grid[0, 0], zorder=2, sharey=x_y)
invx_y.plot(-x, y)
invx_y.margins(0)

invx_invy = fig.add_subplot(grid[1, 0], zorder=0, sharex=invx_y)
invx_invy.plot(-x, -y)
invx_invy.margins(0)

x_invy = fig.add_subplot(grid[1, 1], zorder=1, sharey=invx_invy, sharex=x_y)
x_invy.plot(x, -y)
x_invy.margins(0)

# clean up overlapping ticks
invx_y.tick_params(labelleft=False, length=0)
invx_invy.tick_params(labelleft=False, labelbottom=False, length=0)
x_invy.tick_params(labelbottom=False, length=0)

x_y.set_xticks(x_y.get_xticks()[1:-1])
invx_y.set_xticks(invx_y.get_xticks()[1:-1])
x_invy.set_yticks(x_invy.get_yticks()[1:-1])

plt.show()
```

This yields the following figure:

[image: 4 plots shared axes 2x2 gridspec example]